# How to remove two same and random characters following each other in string - PHP

Tags: php

Need to remove random `aa/` or `bb/` to `zz/` letters (with slash) to get `/logo/picture.png`

```
$url = "/logo/aa/picture.png";
$url = "/logo/bb/picture.png";
$url = "/logo/cc/picture.png";
```

Comment: Always 2 alpha characters? `/([a-z])\1/` replace with `/`.

Comment: please tell us what you're tried already by [edit]ing your question. did you try searching the web? also, you should specify PHP in the question body.

Comment: well, i tried to figure it out in web how regular expressions syntaxis works, but i have no experience for this. also i put PHP tag, is this necessary to mention it in body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternative which doesn't care what's contained in that url part or what lengths url parts have:

```
$urlParts = explode('/', $url);
array_splice($urlParts, count($urlParts) - 2, 1);
$url = implode('/',  $urlParts);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the $url is always of the form you provided you could do:

```
$str1 = substr($url,0,5);
$str2 = substr($url,8,strlen($url));
$url = $str1.$str2;
```

if it's not always of the same form you could determine the substrings indexes programmatically, maybe using `strpos` function. More detail [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

Answer (score -1):

Luca Angioloni solution is correct but this is more stable:

```
$url preg_replace("/\/[a-z]{2}\//", "/", $url);
```

This will work even on url like: `/img/xz/picture.png` but if you have an url like this `/ig/aa/picture.png` this will remove `/ig` and not `/aa`

Comment: That is not valid `preg_replace` syntax. That also is too loose and will replace the `mg` of `img`.

Comment: I have check the the syntax from https://regex101.com/ but has you say maybe is better this `$url = preg_replace("\/[a-z]{2}\/", "/", $url);`

Comment: Now i have test it and this one is working `preg_replace("/\/[a-z]{2}\//", "/", $url);` But if the url is `/ig/aa/picture.img` it is still wrong

Comment: @Bizzy your last code is working for my situation, but BVEngerov's suggestion is more flexible, thanx for answer!